# Google Maps Street View getStatus()

Tags: javascript, undefined, google-street-view

I have the map view as default when the page is loaded and with a button that runs the toggle function below to switch from map view to street view.

However when the street view is not available street view goes back to the map view automatically and the getStatus() function returns 'undefined' instead of ZERO_RESULTS. So I cannot catch that the street view is not available.

Do you have any suggestion on how I could handle the issue?

Thanks!

```
var panorama;

function initMap() {
    var my_pos = {lat: 1 * $("#mapstreet").data('lat'), lng: 1 * $("#mapstreet").data('lng')};
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
        zoom: 15,
        center: my_pos
        });
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: my_pos,
        map: map
    });
    panorama = map.getStreetView();
    panorama.setPosition(my_pos);
    console.log(panorama.getStatus()); // This line returns 'undefined' for both available and unavailable street views
}

function toggleStreetView() {
    var toggle = panorama.getVisible();
    if (!toggle) {
        panorama.setVisible(true);
    } else {
        panorama.setVisible(false);
    }
}
```

Comment: Ever have any luck resolving this?  I'm running into the same issue .....

Comment: Sorry, no luck until now.